# Working with Trello offline and synchronization

Tags: trello, sync

Will the Android app work without internet connectivity and sync with Trello when the internet becomes available?

Can the Android app be controlled as to when to sync with Trello?

We work at sea and would like to use the Android app for storing project data then sync the data with Trello after reviewing/editing project information.

Are we able to store project data offsite from Trello for our own records once a project is complete?

Answer (score 2):

You can add cards and view cards and add comments to existing cards while offline, but you cannot add comments to new cards you create while offline.  You also cannot view comments, descriptions, or checklists while offline.  Changes will be synced when you reconnect to the internet and run Trello.

You can export your Trello board to JSON format, but I'm not sure what can read that format.  Business users can export to CSV.

Based on these limitations, it probably would not work for your purposes.  You might consider Google Drive or something similar that allows you to work offline and sync when you do go online.

Comment: +1 good summary of the current state of play. They're working on improving this (see my new answer), but it'll be a long time. For me "cannot view comments, descriptions or checklists" is the major dealbreaker here.

Comment: Since you wrote this answer, Trello have announced offline support for their mobile apps: https://blog.trello.com/trello-mobile-offline

Answer (score 1):

The Trello team [announced in May 2015](https://trello.com/c/ig5IZyJn/291-offline-support#) that offline support is something they are "working on".

That said, it's been crawling through their features process since 2012, and they warn "it will be a long while", so don't hold your breath. You can use the above link to subscribe to this proposal, and/or vote in support of this proposal (at time of writing, it had 3,214 votes and was one of the most popular requests).

Here's the key information from that link:

> ### Offline support *in list Working on*
>
> *3214 votes*
>
> Yes, we are working on this. We have a plan on what we need to do.
>   It's a big project and it will be a long while before we have
>   something to show you.
>
> - Daniel Lew moved this card from **Up next** to **Working on**
>     27 May 2015 at 18:23
> - Hamid Palo moved this card from **Feature Ideas** to **Up next** 17 Dec 2014 at 15:23
> - Hamid Palo added this card to **Future Features** 15 Aug 2012 at 14:15

Comment: Trello now works offline in the mobile apps: https://blog.trello.com/trello-mobile-offline

Answer (score 0):

Just installed Trello. Seems like it's designed for offline viewing, not offline editing.

Perhaps Evernote might be a better option, although it's not really a project management tool.

Answer (score 0):

Trello announced in 2017 that [the Trello mobile apps work offline](https://blog.trello.com/trello-mobile-offline). This includes:

- Creating new boards, lists and cards
- Assign members to cards
- Add descriptions, dates, labels and checklists to cards
- Leave comments and reaction emojis
- Attach pictures to cards

Changes that you make while offline will be synced once you go online again.